# Неизвестный тип URL при парсинге

Tags: python, lxml, urllib

Выдает ошибку в ссылке, как я понимаю, потому что urllib непонятным образом обрезает её при переходе на новую страницу. 
Как ни странно, в поиске яндекса при аналогичном алгоритме всё работает.

**raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)**

**ValueError: unknown url type: '/searchTerms/search?query=python...**

```
from lxml.html import *
import urllib.request

headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'}
req=urllib.request.Request('https://search.disconnect.me',None, headers)
page=fromstring(urllib.request.urlopen(req).read())

page.forms[0].fields['query']='python'
result=parse(submit_form(page.forms[0])).getroot()
```

Comment: не по теме: избегай `import *` вне интерактивной консоли или `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`urllib` не обрезает адреса. `urllib` не распознаёт содержимое, которое оно читает. `urllib` c одинаковым успехом скачает и картинку и html страничку.

Чтобы получить полный адрес, можно вызвать `lxml.html.make_links_absolute()` функцию. Полезно посмотреть на `base_url` свойство и как оно используется.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как это применимо к моему коду.

Comment: @ND7: посмотрите на ошибку в вопросе. Подумайте почему адрес в ошибке не начинается с `http://example.com` и что должно произойти, если вызвать `make_links_absolute()`.